# Can Rust detect a possible stack overflow at compile time?

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

Can Rust detect a possible stack overflow at compile time? I found it can optimize tail recursion, but a generic recursion causes runtime error:

```rust
fn rec(mut i: i32) {
    i = i - 1;
    if i > 0 {
        rec(i);
    }
    println!("{}", i);
}

fn main() {
    rec(100000000);
}
```

Comment: I think the closest you can get is using [cargo-call-stack](https://github.com/japaric/cargo-call-stack) by japaric. But I'm not sure if you can detect it with that.

Comment: Stack size is not necessarily known at compile time, so static detection is impossible in the general case (equivalent to the halting problem, I'm 99% sure).

Comment: @trentcl: Well, actually... a number of embedded coding standards will specifically forbid recursion (and pointer-to-function calls) specifically to be able to determine the full call graph and infer the maximum stack size from there (though the analysis is performed on the assembly). It can even be possible to use recursion if you can prove that there is a bound on the number of recursive calls -- passing a "steps" integer if necessary to guarantee it -- in some coding standards. All those are simple, practical work-arounds around the halting problem.

Comment: I guess this is the time where we should speak about the `become` keyword, and its possible use to guarantee tail-recursion in the future...